# Android Facebook SDK v4 LikeView issue

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I'm trying to implement the Facebook "Like Button" in my Android app. Before I was using the Facebook SDK v3 where you would set up the LikeView and then call likeView.handleOnActivityResult(context, requestCode, resultCode, data) inside of onActivityResult(); This would change the button so that after the page was "liked" it would show "Liked" and the number of people that also like the page.

Now, I'm using the Facebook SDK v4 because v3 is now deprecated. In this version, I do not see any documentation or anyway to have this same type of functionality for the "like" button. It no longer has the likeView.handlePnActivityResult method that v3 had. Now when the user hits the "like" button and likes the page, it doesn't change the state of the button.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue so that it will have the same functionality as the LikeView in the Facebook SDK v3?

Here is the code of what I'm doing:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Initialize FaceBook SDK
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);

    // Set up ActionBar
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    terms = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.terms_holder);
    privacyPolicy = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.privacy_policy_holder);
    share = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.social_media_holder);
    environmentButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.environment_change);
    likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);

    likeView.setObjectIdAndType("##############", LikeView.ObjectType.PAGE);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // In the old Facebook SDK this is where it would change the like button to "liked 2,038" but this code is deprecated now apparently
    // likeView.handleOnActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

And here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/social_media_holder"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:onClick="onClick" >


<com.facebook.share.widget.LikeView
    android:id="@+id/like_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" />           


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text="@string/post_about_us"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey" />
```

Comment: You need to implement a CallbackManager and then, in onActivityResult, pass off the result to it via: callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Guardanis's answer is correct (Question's comment section).
But this is the code for it ( I used).

in onCreate(...)

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

in onActivityResult(...)

```
 callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

Comment: this does not work for me. I am using Parse API for Facebook login and I have also added ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);  in onActivityResult() method.

Comment: I have resolved this, I was missed to add Tester/developer to the Facebook app.

Comment: Worked! Thank you! Wha this is not mentioned in Facebook doc?!

Answer (score 0):

Native Like Button: The Native Like Button, designed for mobile apps, will no longer be supported starting with Facebook SDK version 4.28 and above. Previous versions of the SDK can still use the Native Like Button, but starting 2/6, the Native Like Button will no longer be supported. After 2/6, the dialogs for Native Like will no longer appear and taps on any native like button will result in no action.

Comment: OK, but you offer  no solution!

Comment: Because now there is no native solution.